# Do homeomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ have zero topological entropy?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, entropy

I have two questions:

(1) Does a homeomorphism on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ have zero topological entropy?

(2) Does a homeomorphism on $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}:=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$ have zero topological entropy?

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to answer this.

**Edit**

For my first question, my naive answer would be yes by using that $\bar{\mathbb{R}}\cong [0,1]$:

Let $f\colon\bar{\mathbb{R}}\to\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be a homeomorphism.
Since we have a homeomorphism $\varphi\colon \bar{\mathbb{R}}\to [0,1]$, we should be able to define
$$
g\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]
$$
by
$$
g=\varphi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}
$$
which is a homeomorphism on $[0,1]$ and therefore has zero topological entropy, $h([0,1],g)=0$. Since $\varphi\circ f=g\circ\varphi$ and $\varphi$ is continuous and bijective, this should imply
$$
h(\bar{\mathbb{R}},f)=h([0,1],g)=0.
$$

Comment: You need to tell us what are the topologies.

Comment: Each open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is also open in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and for $\infty$ and $-\infty$ a neighborhoud system is given: For each $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $[-\infty,a[:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x<a\}\cup\{-\infty\}$ is an open neighbourhood for $-\infty$ and $]a,+\infty]$ an open neighbourhood for $+\infty$. - same for the topology on $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for (1) is correct, assuming two facts (of course): homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$ have zero entropy; and entropy is invariant under topological conjugation.

To prove (2) you need to analyze the homeomorphism $f : \overline{\mathbb{Z}} \to \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$, in particular you need to list certain properties of its invariant sets. First, the set $\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ is invariant by $f$ (because those are the only two non-isolated points of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$). Second, every invariant subset of the restricted homeomorphism $f | \mathbb{Z}$ is an open subset of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ (because every point of $\mathbb{Z}$ is an isolated point of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$); it follows that $\mathbb{Z}$ is partitioned into its minimal $f$-invariant subsets, each of which is an orbit of $f$, and each of which is open in $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$. Finally, the orbits of $f | \mathbb{Z}$ come in one of two types: finite periodic orbits; and infinite orbits on which the restriction is topologically conjugate to the shift map $n \mapsto n+1$ on the whole of $\mathbb{Z}$. Once you have these properties, it should be pretty easy to prove that the entropy equals zero.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. Suppose $f\colon\bar{\mathbb{Z}}\to\bar{\mathbb{Z}}, x\mapsto x+a$ for some integer $a$. Then is a monoton homeomorphism. Is it possible to express $f$ as a monoton homeomorphism on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Sure, simply pick a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $(-\infty,+\infty)$ which you then extend to the endpoints, and topologically conjugate the formula $x \mapsto x+a$ by that homeomorphism.

Comment: Why is the new homeomorphidm on [0,1] then monotone, too?

Comment: Let me suggest that perhaps you might want to post a new question about monotone homeomorphisms of intervals. Long discussions on new questions buried in comments is not a good idea.

Comment: Good idea! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570572/monotone-homeomorphism-on-0-1

Comment: Coming back to the Original question Here: Isnt it always possible to do the same Proof Strategy for (2) which I Used for (1), i.e. create a homeomorphism on [0,1] and use conjugacy?

Comment: No, it's not possible, because a self-homeomorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ need not preserve the order. For example, perhaps your homeomorphism $f : \overline{\mathbb{Z}} \to \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ adds 2 to each even integer and subtracts $4$ from each odd integer, while fixing each of $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not See your Point. Why not restricting the $\phi$ on $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ and use again conjugacy?

Comment: For the map $f$ in my previous comment, if you wish to prove it has entropy zero by conjugating it to some kind of well-behaved homeomorphism $g : \overline{\mathbb{Z}} \to \overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ then you will have to say explicitly what you want $g$ to be. I'll warn you to avoid all maps $g$ of the form $x \mapsto x+a$, because $f$ is not conjugate to any such map.

Comment: I was not thinking about conjugating f to some g on $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ but again to some homeomorphism on [0,1]. - But I guess this only Works if f can be continuously extended from $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: Since $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are not homeomorphic, that's not going to be possible.

Comment: Ok, Extension is the wrong word since the Ranges are different. What I mean is: Suppose we have a Self-homeomorphism $f$ on $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ and a self-homeomorphism $g$ on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $g$ restricted on $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}$ equals f.  Say $g(x)=x+a$ for integer a. Then the Image of integers are integers. Maybe on this Situation it is possible to use the conjugation Argument to Argue that f has top. Entropy Zero since the top. Entropy of an Invariant Subset is smaller than or Equal the entropy of the Whole System which Here is Zero. Hence f has zero entropy.

Comment: That method will not work for general self-homeomorphisms of $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$, because of examples, like the one in my comments, that are not the restriction to $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ of any self-homeomorphism of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Ok, in General it does not work. But for Special examples like the one I gave?