# Monotone homeomorphism on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\bar{\mathbb{Z}}:=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$.

Suppose $f:\bar{\mathbb{Z}}\to\bar{\mathbb{Z}},x\mapsto x+a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f$ is a monotone homeomorphism.

Is it possible to express $f$ as a monotone homeomorphism $g\colon [0,1]\to [0,1]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to conjugate $f$ by a homeomorphism $\bar h : [0,1] \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ which is an extension of an increasing homeomorphism $h : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$.

For example, let $h : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the homeomorphism
$$h(x) = \tan\left(\frac{(2x-1)\pi}{2}\right)
$$
Let $\bar h : [0,1] \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the homeomorphism that extends $h$, namely
$$\bar h(x) = \begin{cases}
h(x) &\text{if $x \in (0,1)$} \\
-\infty &\text{if $x=0$} \\
+\infty &\text{if $x=1$}
\end{cases}
$$
Define
$$g(x) = \bar h^{-1}\left(\bar h(x) + a\right)
$$

Comment: Why are you using $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and not $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$? Isnt this Important?

Comment: I think your expression is for the continuous Extension from f to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (and therefore holds, in particular for the Restriction, i.e. the Original f)?

Comment: Your question was a little vague, so I interpreted it generously to mean "Is it possible to express $f$ as the restriction to $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ of a homeomorphism $\overline{\mathbb{R}} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ which is topologically conjugate to a monotone homeomorphism $g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$?". A narrower interpretation would have been "Is it possible to express $f$ as being topologically conjugate to a monotone homeomorphism $g : [0,1] \to [0,1]$?" in which case the answer would have been a simple "No", because $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: And as this restriction.. it has topological entropy 0 since it is the restriction of a Zero entropy map on an invariant subset. (In order to make the Link to the other question), Right?

Comment: That would be a roundabout way to show that your $f$ has zero entropy, because it's pretty easy to prove directly using the definition.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't it be $h(x)=\tan(\frac{(2x-1)\pi}{2})$ since the inner function is a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ while $\tan$ is a homeomorphism from $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the correction.

Comment: But this should not change your argument since both arctan and tan are increasing on $(0,1)$.